# Extended permissions with fb:login-button

Tags: permissions, facebook-c#-sdk

I am following Facebook C# SDK sample on the following link: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Documentation

Login works fine, but requesting extended permissions doesn't seem to have an effect on Login Dialog. Here is how I request the extended permissions:

```
<fb:login-button scope="publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

The authorization dialog from Facebook doesn't show anything about me requesting publish_stream permission.

Am I doing something wrong?